# Deployiong rails app to digital ocean dokku ssh key not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, dokku

I want to deploy rails app to digital ocean.
I use this turorial:
http://blog.flatironschool.com/using-digital-ocean-and-dokku-for-easier-rails-app-deploys/

When I do this:

> First, you’ll need to copy your computer’s public SSH key. Go to your terminal and run this:
>   $ cat /.ssh/idrsa.pub

I get the following output:

```
    jonstark@jonstark-pc:~$ cat /.ssh/idrsa.pub
cat: /.ssh/idrsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

What are my next actions? (I am really newbie to ubuntu).
I understand that may be I should ask this question in another place. So if it so feel to tell me where.

Okay. I did something after googling. Here what I did:

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jonstark/.ssh/id_rsa): ocean
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in ocean.
Your public key has been saved in ocean.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
b6:8e:de:5f:37:2f:b6:96:d2:53:16:89:ef:a8:1c:5a jonstark@jonstark-pc
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|              . .|
|             . o |
|        S     . .|
|       . .     .o|
|        .  E..=+ |
|       +  +.ooB+ |
|     .o oo.o.+.+.|
+-----------------+
```

Then I found this generated ocean.pub file and copy paste the ssh key to digital ocean

But I gues I did everything wrong and I should not store the key in ocean.pub but in /.ssh/idrsapub instead.

Okay also I did this:

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~$  ssh-copy-id dokku@45.55.21.53
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: No identities found
```

I am still confused

What do I do now?

Comment: try the command without the first "/": `cat .ssh/idrsa.pub` first

Comment: the same no such file or derictory)

Answer (score 0):

To get your public key in ubuntu you can try cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

If that doesn`t work you probably have to setup your ssh keys.
A good tutorial step by step can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)

Comment: see my updated answer  I googled the same link and generated ssh key. But I placed it in file ocean.pub. Is it bad?

Comment: By default, ssh searches for id_dsa and id_rsa files. The keys do not have to be named like this, you can name it ocean as well and place it in a different directory as well, but in that case, you have to specify the key explicitly.

Comment: so basically right now I should create id_rsa.pub file ( in home directory?) then copy paste there the key I have stored in ocean.pub?

Comment: try something like this ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/ocean.pub dokku@45.55.21.53

Comment: `jonstark@jonstark-pc:~$ ssh-copy-id -i ~/ocean.pub dokku@45.55.21.53
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 2 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
dokku@45.55.21.53's password:` 
Right now I don't have dokku password cause digital ocean is registered to client's email and I don't have access to it. But is okay? I will get pass input it and key will be installed?)