# Deploy rails app to digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I use this tutorial for DO dokku deployment:
http://blog.flatironschool.com/using-digital-ocean-and-dokku-for-easier-rails-app-deploys/
I messed up with adding ssh keys here are the details:

[Deployiong rails app to digital ocean dokku ssh key not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460305/deployiong-rails-app-to-digital-ocean-dokku-ssh-key-not-found/35460755?noredirect=1#comment58618673_35460755)

So I decided to skip part and go on.
I did the next step:

```
 git remote add dokku dokku@45.55.21.53:main
```

Then 
`git push dokku master`
I asked to enter password

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects/car_main$ git push dokku master
dokku@45.55.21.53's password:
```

on email I got this:

```
Droplet Name: main
IP Address: 45.55.21.53
Username: root
Password: 0772f867514dc546
```

So I copy pasted this password but it says permission denied. Or something like this:
`Permission denied (publickey,password).`
Is this because I messed up with
 ssh keys or not?
I copy pasted password several times and entered it manually twice. So it is highly unlikely that I misspelled password.

And what are my next action?

Comment: The first time you SSH into your droplet, were you asked to changed the password? Because, as far as I know, you NEED (and prompted) to change the droplet password at the first login

Comment: I deleted droplet an created new. Then I logged from DO console and changed password, so this is actually a solved question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you SSH into your droplet, were you asked to changed the password?

Because you NEED (and you're prompted) to change the droplet password at the first login!

Comment: I will  mark this as answer but I didn't  log with ssh cause I messed up with ssh key=)

Comment: I have another question that drives me really crazy cause I have no idea whats wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478863/dokku-error-var-lib-dokku-plugins-available-pg-plugin-plugin-toml-no-such-file

Comment: SSH is a method to log into the machine. Different method but with the same objetive. Log into the machine to change the password.

Comment: I got it. You answer seems clear that's why I accepted it. I destroyed droplet, create new, then managed to configure ssh key) now I don't have this question anymore, I moved on=)