# Dokku error /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/pg-plugin/plugin.toml: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

So here what I did and the following output:

```
root@ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01:/var/lib/dokku/plugins# dokku postgres:link DATABASE ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01
2016/02/18 05:24:38 open /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/pg-plugin/plugin.toml: no such file or directory
2016/02/18 05:24:38 open /var/lib/dokku/plugins/available/pg-plugin/plugin.toml: no such file or directory
no config vars for ubuntu-512mb-sfo1-01
```

Can someone help me? I try to deploy rails to digital ocean.
I use http://blog.flatironschool.com/using-digital-ocean-and-dokku-for-easier-rails-app-deploys/  - this tutorial but it seems to be horribly outdated. I ran into so many errors so I am thinking of giving this up and staying with heroku hosting.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you don't have a Postgres docker container active. Take a look at the [dokku-pg-pluging](https://github.com/Kloadut/dokku-pg-plugin) to know how to configure and instantiate a postgres docker container.

By the way, since your objective is to change from Heroku to DigitalOcean, and you're having trouble using dokku, may I suggest you using [deploy bot](http://deploybot.com/) instead? I did managed to successfully deploy an rails 4 app to DigitalOcean using deploy bot. Follow this [tutorial](http://deploybot.com/guides/deploy-ruby-on-rails-to-digitalocean). And you can easily follow [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) with deploy bot, adapting the unicorn and nginx stop/start services with the hooks that deploy bot provides.

Edit:
Since you wanted a more specific answer for the deploy bot solution, here goes my approach (this was +/- 3/4 months ago):

1. Create the droplet and follow the guide to create a droplet, install ruby, rails, unicorn and nginx and the script to control unicorn (it's in the tutorial).
2. Configure the deploy bot and make sure you run `bundle install` and another rails' specific commands (changing environments and so on) after the upload (this is a predefined hook).
3. The last command should be `service nginx restart` to restart the server (using the script from step 1).
4. Profit!

Comment: Is it easier than dokku? Cause I hear about unicron the first time and description like this `Unicorn is an application server, like Passenger or Puma,` tells me nothing)  Also I have no idea about nginx stop/start services and your answer seems half a magic to me ( and i've read about deploy bot and It seems that you need to deploy rails app and only then you will be able to automate ur actions so I am not sure that I want to automate deploying cause first step is just to deploy)

Comment: Did you got it? Or do you need more help @user2950593?